# SQL Joining tables with 'constants'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table of orders,

```
Invoice   Location    Customer Code   SalesPersonEmail
------------------------------------------------------
300001    001         CUS001          ?
300002    006         CUS002          ?
```

And a table of email groups,

```
Role              Email 
-----------------------------------------------------
Filtered_Group    Management@gmail.com;john@gmail.com
```

When Location = 001, SalesPersonEmail must be the Email field from Filtered_Group

SalesPersonEmail for all other locations must be "Orders@gmail.com;" + the Email for Role No_Filter_Group.

I'm currently using the following to achieve this,

```
SELECT i.Invoice, i.Location, i.[Customer Code], 
    CASE WHEN i.Location = 001 
         THEN f.Email 
         ELSE N'Orders@gmail.com;' + nf.Email as SalesPersonEmail
    END
FROM   Invoice i, RoleCodes f, RoleCodes nf
WHERE  f.Role = N'Filtered_Group' AND nf.Role = N'No_Filter_Group'
```

My problem is the Role No_Filter_Group may not exist in the Role table at times, which causes the above query to return nothing.

How do I join these tables properly so if *No_Filter_Group* does not exist in the table, rows that have a *SalesPersonEmail* of *Filtered_Group* are still returned from the query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively simple way is to use `LEFT JOIN` and put the special number `001` for your location and special role names `Filtered_Group` and `No_Filter_Group` in the join condition.

In this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c6a6/2/0) you can comment/uncomment one line in the schema definition to see how it works when `RoleCodes` has a row with `No_Filter_Group` and when it doesn't.

In any case, the query would return all rows from `Invoice` table.

```
SELECT
  Invoice.Invoice
  ,Invoice.Location
  ,Invoice.[Customer Code]
  ,CASE WHEN Invoice.Location = '001'
  THEN RoleCodes.Email
  ELSE 'Orders@gmail.com;' + ISNULL(RoleCodes.Email, '')
  END AS SalesPersonEmail
FROM
  Invoice
  LEFT JOIN RoleCodes ON
    (Invoice.Location = '001' 
    AND RoleCodes.Role = 'Filtered_Group')
    OR
    (Invoice.Location <> '001' 
    AND RoleCodes.Role = 'No_Filter_Group')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

**Note:** This is just a example am not sure about the tables and column of your schema. Replace with the respective tables and columns

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN location = '001' THEN (SELECT TOP 1 email 
                                     FROM   email_table 
                                     WHERE  [role] = 'Filtered_Group') 
         ELSE 'Orders@gmail.com;' 
       END 
FROM   orders
```

If email_table table will have only one row for `[role] = 'Filtered_Group'` then you can remove the `TOP 1` from the `sub-query`

Answer (score 0):

Left join or an easier, albeit less efficient method would be to do a subquery in the select statement itself.

```
SELECT i.Invoice, i.Location, i.[Customer Code], 
    CASE WHEN i.Location = 001 
             THEN (SELECT TOP 1 f.Email FROM RoleCodes f WHERE f.Role = N'Filtered_Group')
         ELSE N'Orders@gmail.com;' + ISNULL( (SELECT nf.Email as SalesPersonEmail FROM  RoleCodes nf WHERE nf.Role = N'No_Filter_Group'), '')
    END
FROM   Invoice i
```

Normally you would want to join these in on each other but I'm not certain how you would do that with the schema provided.

Answer (score 0):

Nested select will be run for each row, instead, you could try this :-

```
Select   i.Invoice
        ,i.Location
        ,i.CustomerCode
        ,Isnull(r.Email,'Orders@gmail.com') As SalesPersonEmail
From    Invoice As i With (Nolock)
        Left Join 
        (
            Select   rc.Email
                    ,'001' As Location
            From    RoleCodes As rc With (Nolock)
            Where   rc.Role = 'Filtered_Group'
        ) As r On i.Location = r.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following Query:

```
      select t.Invoice,t.Location,t.[Customer Code],
      case t.Location
      when '001' then 
           t2.Email
      else
          'Orders@gmail.com'
      end
      as 
      Salespersonemail
      from orders t
      join email_groups t2 on t2.Role='Filtered_Group'
```